# Show that the set is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For a fixed m x n matrix $A$, show directly that the set {$b$|$Ax$ = $b$ is consistent} is a vector space.

1) It contains the zero vector

{o | $Ax$ = 0b is consistent}

2) it is closed under addition

let $b,d$ $\in$ col(A)

{$b+d$ | $Ax$ = $b+d$ is consistent} }

3) it is closed under multiplication

let c $\in$ $R$

{$cb$ | $Ax$ = $cb$ is consistent}}

are these steps the correct way to prove that the set {b|Ax = b is consistent} is a vector space?

Comment: in part 3, it should somehow indicate scalar multiplication, and you ought to have $c \in \mathbb R$ rather than what you put

Comment: None of these are really proofs, you just wrote down sets, and their meaning is not clear.

Comment: @Arnaud then what is the right way to make these proofs then?

Comment: Your working is pretry good but you need to claim explicitely somewhere that $Ax=b$ is consistent if and only if $b $ is in the column space of $A$. Then you can  cite the result which tells us that the span of columns of a matrix is actually a vector subspace (ie a vector space ).

Comment: I can see what you mean in each part, but your presentation of the solutions is not really a valid way to go about things

Comment: Suppose $b$ is such that $Ax=b$ is consistent.  Further suppose that $d$ is such that $Ax=d$ is consistent.  We wish to prove that $Ax=(b+d)$ is also consistent.  Indeed... since $Ax=b$ is consistent, this implies that there exists some $x_1$ such that $Ax_1=b$ and since $Ax=d$ is consistent this implies that there exists some $x_2$ such that $Ax_2=d$.  These together imply that....  and therefore.... which implies that....